# How to pass specialized arguments to a factory template?

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, architecture

Imagine you have a base class (eg `Animal`) and a factory (`AnimalFactory`) using a template method to execute the same operations (using different details) to create an instance. `AnimalFactory` accepts `AnimalDetails` to be able to build up the animal:

*I use pseudo-code to make to problem generic enough.*

```
class Animal {}
class AnimalDetails {}
class AnimalFactory {

    makeBaby:Animal(details:AnimalDetails) { /* some special action */ }

    createTemplate:Animal (details:AnimalDetails) {
        makeBaby(details)
        return baby
    }

}
```

Then I create a subclass Bird and Mammal with their factories and specialized params:

```
class Bird:Animal {}
class BirdDetails:AnimalDetails {}

class Mammal:Animal {}
class MammalDetails:AnimalDetails {}

class BirdFactory:AnimalFactory {

    makeBaby:Bird(details:BirdDetails) { /* bird specific action using bird details */

}
class MammalFactory:AnimalFactory {

    makeBaby:Mammal(details:MammalDetails) { /* mammal specific action using bird details */

}
```

This is obviously not type correct, as the template method (`AnimalFactory.createTemplate`) is expecting an `AnimalDetails` parameter.

I've spent some time to come up with type correct solutions that is using the template and flexible on the input type (as far as it's fitting the factory subclass methods) - but nothing was good enough. Could you think of a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Which Factory are you trying to use? There are three variants: Concrete Factory (which doesn't use polymorphism), Factory Method (which has a polymorphic create method, subclasses decide) and Abstract Factory (which uses object composition to create families of related objects without having to depend on their concrete classes).

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm not understanding this enough - I'd say it's a mixture of abstract factory and factory method with a twist of using input that has a common interface (base class). Btw thanks for the listing, it's useful to know these different types of factory patter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, factory pattern is applied when all the concrete factories can instantiate a different implementation by just having the same input as the abstract factory has. Your example shows that you have different input for concrete factories than the abstract one has. That means, you are not correctly using the Factory pattern.

To correct this, you need to **make input creation an implementation detail**.

Many ways can be found to accomplish this. I can tell you 2 options:

1. Have factory of AnimalFactories. So, this factory (creator) creates AnimalFactory by taking nothing. In different implementations, they construct and pass concrete AnimalDetail instances to the concrete AnimalFactory instances.
2. Make your factories more self-contained. Pass them nothing, and let the concrete implementation construct and use the concrete AnimalDetail.

In short, this means, AnimalDetail **is not really an abstract thing** - it's just *different* from case to case. If it was really abstract, your consumers would be able to use it without knowing the difference. But it's not the case. Based on this finding, I don't see a real need to have AnimalDetail as abstract type at all.

Comment: Thanks @Tengiz for the explanation. I was thinking about both the ways you recommended, and the factory-factory seemed the best way to go - I tried to implement it without the overhead of a full second factory: https://gist.github.com/itarato/ba9c72af4ad16f9b46ef Do you think this makes any sense?

Comment: I have to say not really. Factory that you have takes the type of the resulting object as an argument, so it can't be called a factory then. Just think about it - if you know what kind of object you need (since you're passing it to the factory), then why don't you simply create this object without using the factory at all? factory is not just responsible to call a "new" operator for you - it's more than that. Factory is an abstract thing, that makes the concrete type creation irrelevant to the consumer code. You're doing completely opposite thing.

Comment: What I expect in my case (factory or not) is a set of methods that will shape the newly created object (template functions) - same for all subtypes. Also my "factory" has a cache which makes decision on new object creation or loading from cache. I know my solution was ugly, however couldn't figure out any better so far. Thanks for the guides ;)

Comment: You seem a little confused about patterns. Factory is useful (as I said before) when the consuming code does not care about the difference between an Animal and a Bird. If it does care, then Factory is not the pattern you need. If your code simply wants to explicitly (!) manipulate either Animal or Bird, it can construct them directly. If construction is not a straightforward or is an involved process, then you can have helper function (maybe static) do that for you - and you don't need Factory pattern then. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply the [abstract factory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) pattern? Take a look at the real world code in the link.

Comment: Thanks @Gnucki - it's very close, however the one difference which seems important is the "recipe", the input parameter. The example you've pointed out is self contained. I my case needs a bit different structure.